# How to debug envoy unit tests on VScode mac

Tags: visual-studio-code, bazel, envoyproxy

I am working with envoy (https://github.com/envoyproxy/envoy). I got this project to build and debug on mac in VSCode using `--spawn_strategy=standalone --genrule_strategy=standalone` flags when I do bazel build.

However, when I try the same with bazel test, I can't get it to run without sandbox. When I run the command: 
`bazel test //:test_name --spawn_strategy=standalone --genrule_strategy=standalone`
It runs the whole test and shows which tests passed and which ones failed.

But when I run the binary from /bazel-bin/ as `./test_name`, it gives me an error saying: `Caught Abort trap: 6, suspect faulting address`. I am assuming this is because of some missing env variables created in sandbox - I have also tried just using `--strategy=TestRunner=standalone`. Is it possible to run it standalone? so that I can debug in an IDE such as VScode. Thank you!